# Java Xmemcached or Spymemcached client unable to get the key value which is set by C# Enyim client

Tags: java, c#, spymemcached, enyim, xmemcached

***Java*** **Xmemcached** or **Spymemcached** client are unable to get the correct value from memcached by key which is set by **C#** **Enyim** client.

We have already tried set C# MemcachedProtocol.Binary to Text to store basic String format data, but both Java Xmemcached client and Spymemcached client are not able to get the data. The errors are below:

```
2018-01-11 11:08:06.655 [ERROR] [main] BaseSerializingTranscoder: Failed to decompress data
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:91) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.gzipDecompress(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:274) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.decompress(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:219) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.decode(SerializingTranscoder.java:87) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.fetch0(XMemcachedClient.java:657) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get0(XMemcachedClient.java:1085) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1043) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1065) [xmemcached-2.4.0.jar:?]
```

If we use StringTranscoder(), the error will be decoding String error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Decode String error
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.StringTranscoder.decode(StringTranscoder.java:35)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.StringTranscoder.decode(StringTranscoder.java:11)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.fetch0(XMemcachedClient.java:657)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get0(XMemcachedClient.java:1085)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1043)
at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.get(XMemcachedClient.java:1065)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fix by writing a custom transcoder and ignoring the GZIP/ZIP flag part.